# Just updated RavenDB to rev. 2230 from rev. 960 and on calling session.SaveChanges() I have JsonSerialization exception

Tags: c#, json, ravendb

I was a little eager to test new official version of RavenDB that Ayende just put online and after updating it in my project([link to Github](https://github.com/capaj/Democracy-2.0)), I was caught off guard by this exception(sry for the long stacktrace). Does anyone have a clue what might be causing it?

> Error getting value from 'ScopeId' on 'System.Net.IPAddress'.
>
> at Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object 
>   target) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\DynamicValueProvider.cs:line
>   108    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   364    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs:line
>   61    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line
>   608    at
>   Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Imports\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line
>   580    at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJToken.FromObjectInternal(Object o,
>   JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJToken.cs:line
>   80    at Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject.FromObject(Object o,
>   JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\RavenJObject.cs:line
>   156    at Raven.Client.Document.EntityToJson.GetObjectAsJson(Object
>   entity) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\EntityToJson.cs:line
>   63    at Raven.Client.Document.EntityToJson.ConvertEntityToJson(String
>   key, Object entity, RavenJObject metadata) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\EntityToJson.cs:line
>   35    at
>   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.EntityChanged(Object
>   entity, DocumentMetadata documentMetadata) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line
>   876    at
>   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.b__10(KeyValuePair`2
>   pair) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line
>   739    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() 
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.PrepareForEntitiesPuts(SaveChangesData
>   result) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line
>   739    at
>   Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.PrepareForSaveChanges()
>   in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line
>   732    at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.SaveChanges() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentSession.cs:line
>   483    at Dem2Server.EntityRepository.StoreToDB(ServerClientEntity
>   entity) in
>   d:\Github\Democracy-2.0\Dem2Server\Dem2Server\EntityRepository.cs:line
>   160    at Dem2Server.EntityRepository.Add(ServerClientEntity entity)
>   in
>   d:\Github\Democracy-2.0\Dem2Server\Dem2Server\EntityRepository.cs:line
>   87    at Dem2Model.User.LogInUser(String FBgraphJSON) in
>   d:\Github\Democracy-2.0\Dem2Server\Dem2Server\user.cs:line 171    at
>   Dem2Server.Dem2Hub.ResolveMessage(String message, IWebSocketConnection
>   socket) in
>   d:\Github\Democracy-2.0\Dem2Server\Dem2Server\Dem2Hub.cs:line 74    at
>   Dem2Server.dem2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Main>b__7(String
>   message) in d:\Github\Democracy-2.0\Dem2Server\Dem2Server\dem2.cs:line
>   100    at
>   Fleck.WebSocketServer.<>c__DisplayClass8.<OnClientConnect>b__4(String
>   s)    at Fleck.Handlers.Hybi13Handler.ProcessFrame(FrameType
>   frameType, Byte[] data, Action`1 onMessage, Action onClose, Action`1
>   onBinary)    at
>   Fleck.Handlers.Hybi13Handler.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Create>b__6(FrameType
>   op, Byte[] data)    at Fleck.Handlers.Hybi13Handler.ReceiveData(List`1
>   data, ReadState readState, Action`2 processFrame)    at
>   Fleck.Handlers.Hybi13Handler.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Create>b__5(List`1 d)
>   at Fleck.Handlers.ComposableHandler.Receive(IEnumerable`1 data)    at
>   Fleck.WebSocketConnection.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Read>b__a(Int32 r)    at
>   Fleck.SocketWrapper.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Receive>b__8(Task`1 t)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke() 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this one was easy as starting from RavenDB version 2.0 we need to use

```
using Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft;
```

instead of

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

[Newtonsoft.Json was internalized in RavenDB 2.0](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-220) as discussed in [Raven's Community](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&pli=1#!searchin/ravendb/internalize%2420newtonsoft/ravendb/sV5QDf3g7qw/ZV6w0M-xY3UJ)